# How to check database table which has been created in laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, database, migration, schema, laravel-4.2

I'm new in laravel, anyone know how to see database table which has been created? I've been migrate the database and stuck after create table using schema builder. This is my code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::create('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nim');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('level');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get a client for the db you are using and check if the table exists.

Answer (score 0):

The new table name will be "users" because you have given 'users' as the name in the Schema::create function.

You can view the table from `phpmyadmin` if you are using the `mysql` database, which is sat as the default database for laravel.